# I need a regular expression in order to tokenize multiple words inside quotes in c++

Tags: c++, regex

I have an input file that I want to tokenize.
the text is like this:

```
MATERIAL  "A992Fy50"    TYPE "Steel"    GRADE "Grade 50"    WEIGHTPERVOLUME 0.007849048
```

The tricky part is to get the "Grade 50" as a single word.
could any one suggest a regular expression in c++. I know how to do it without the white space inside the quote with:

```
   const std::string text{"MATERIAL  \"A992Fy50\"    TYPE \"Steel\"    GRADE \"Grade 50\"    WEIGHTPERVOLUME 0.007849048"};
    const std::regex ws_re{"\(\")?(\\s+)\(\")?"}; // whitespace
    std::copy( std::sregex_token_iterator(text.begin(), text.end(), ws_re, -1),
               std::sregex_token_iterator(),
               std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

but this also splits "Grade 50" to Grade and 50.

Comment: Are you sure you want a [regex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex), and not a grammar [parser](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/spirit/doc/x3/html/index.html)?  (I did not downvote.)

Comment: I did write a tokenzier and lexical analyzer a while ago. It is too much work. I am looking for a simpler answer. Do I have to go back to that ?

Comment: Maybe.  Maybe not.  I've seen too many examples of people trying to use a regex to do grammar parsing, and find out that when the string is *not regular*, that it's quite difficult to make a *regular* expression that will parse it easily.  (Examples being XML or HTML or XAML or any URL (not just http or https).)

Comment: I am not an expert on regex. So it is pretty difficult for me to know which way to go.

Comment: `regex const re{R"TXT(\s+|"[^"]+"|\S+)TXT"};` to match each "chunk" (including the in-between whitespace), and `copy(sregex_token_iterator(text.begin(), text.end(), re, 0), sregex_token_iterator(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));` to output each chunk on its own line.

Comment: Wow. Amazing. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex is also a text parser that is ready for use straight away, with an efficient expression that is as simple as

```cpp
"([^"]*)"|(\S+)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/wAD9eL/1/).

**EXPLANATION**

```cpp
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S+                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ") (1 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
```

**[C++ code snippet](https://tio.run/##fVFhT8IwFPxMf8VLTUynSCbRCAxJSJxIgtEgagzgUkrBBdYua0cgc78duw0FY2I/NNv13r1791gYns0Z226PfMGW8ZRD05dKR5wGLbTHIj7n60NgxZmWUQvFyhdzEDTgKqSMg9JTByFfaAioL4gFCSrRWEuYLOkHXGfvjYbRN1UJvm8P3H633QMY4Xa9Xr3dXNojDOYM3h5dAz5pzpcF0um3bzKoE1HT/5v36nY7d4NHt//y0Hu@d8Gu2PZV7aJuX9Rw6qBS3i43D@ZO@nhNMBm@4/GJhT/J6OnUstZ7YjFU88BjC7RccKEcBLuzUwzkintMhhvPn5GiIG/j5XzP1zyiRotkY1cmfJ5lUc5DqHAxzb4NvQzJeRmqqfn7R8K8/nT/5WJC2cLzheKRoZLCqFX@wx2OycFEwKRQGo6VWY3xoONIgKrwINQbYjmQWiaMmYyA5FtTjV0A@SKLlJiMNTSboLILjwQ2FSkq7bRsB6Xb7Rc)**:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    auto blah = std::string{"MATERIAL  \"A992Fy50\"    TYPE \"Steel\"    GRADE \"Grade 50\"    WEIGHTPERVOLUME 0.007849048"};
    std::regex reg{R"x("([^"]*)"|(\S+))x"};
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    std::remove_copy_if(std::sregex_token_iterator(blah.begin(), blah.end(), reg, {1, 2}), std::sregex_token_iterator(), 
            std::back_inserter(tokens),
            [](std::string const &s) { return s.empty(); });
    for (auto s: tokens) {
        std::cout << s << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Results**

```
MATERIAL
A992Fy50
TYPE
Steel
GRADE
Grade 50
WEIGHTPERVOLUME
0.007849048
```

Comment: this is quite good. but How to remove the " as well. tnx

Comment: @RingZero. Capture what you need, see update.

Answer (score 1):

I have a problem.

I know, I'll solve it with regular expressions!

I now have two problems; my original problem, and the regular expression.

Alternative:

1. Break string into quote-delimited phrases.  Use `std::string_view::find`, return a vector of `struct phrase{bool quoted; std::string_view str;};`
2. Break non-quoted phrases up by whitespace.

And you are done.

Adding new stuff like escaped quotes or whitespace is easy, and your code is a bunch of C++ rather than write-only regex with unknowable runtime complexity.

Regex is great for doing a quick one-off search and replace under human supervision, but I would avoid using if for anything that matters.

Answer (score 1):

This is best handled by `std::quoted`.  This occurs so often that the standardization committee created a function specifically to handle quoting and unquoting stream IO. See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::string s;
    std::stringstream in{ "MATERIAL  \"A992Fy50\"    TYPE \"Steel\"    GRADE \"Grade 50\"    WEIGHTPERVOLUME 0.007849048" };
    for (; in >> std::quoted(s), in;)
        std::cout << s << '\n';
};
```

Output:

```
MATERIAL
A992Fy50
TYPE
Steel
GRADE
Grade 50
WEIGHTPERVOLUME
0.007849048
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of focusing on finding a token iterator, I focused on a regular expression to match each whole input:

```
std::string s = R"(MATERIAL  "A992Fy50"    TYPE "Steel"    GRADE "Grade 50"    WEIGHTPERVOLUME 0.007849048)";

std::regex e{R"((\w+)\s+("[^"]*"|\d\.\d+))"};

std::sregex_iterator m_end;
std::sregex_iterator m(std::begin(s), std::end(s), e);

for(; m != m_end; ++m)
{
    std::cout << "Full match: "<< m->str(0) << '\n';

    for(auto i = 1U; i < m->size(); ++i)
        std::cout << "    sub " << i << ": " << m->str(i) << '\n';
}
```

*Output:*

```
Full match: MATERIAL  "A992Fy50"
    sub 1: MATERIAL
    sub 2: "A992Fy50"
Full match: TYPE "Steel"
    sub 1: TYPE
    sub 2: "Steel"
Full match: GRADE "Grade 50"
    sub 1: GRADE
    sub 2: "Grade 50"
Full match: WEIGHTPERVOLUME 0.007849048
    sub 1: WEIGHTPERVOLUME
    sub 2: 0.007849048
```

Comment: fantastic !. tnx